# Terrain for MMORPG

Tags: terrain

Im new in game development. I read some papers about LOD and they were always using heightmaps. I got the basic idea what is LOD and what it solves, but yet i am still not sure i understand what i need to do.

So i want to have terrain for open world mmorpg let's say 20x20km.
If i say 1 opengl world space unit will be 1m, than i will have world 
20_000x20_000units. Now if i can have max. resolution of heightmap 8192x8192, it means i will need to encode more than 2x2m in 1 PIXEL. 
That means every detail of the terrain mesh will be lost (for example little crater with diameter 0.3unit). What i am missing? So is the heightmap even used in real games?

Comment: Where do you get the maximum heightmap resolution of 8192x8192 from?

Comment: philipp: i googled something and found topic on cryengine forum and someone wroted that with current engine (it was probably old topic) it is possible to have max. this resolution, so i gaved it as example.

Comment: They might be used, but its not 1 height map for the whole environment. The map is split in world chunks; typically square or hexagons. You have one height map per chunk (for instance), and you load only the chunk you're in and the immediate neighbours.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt: but still i can't never get the detail of what i modeled in any 3rd program, it will be just approximation, even if i will have bigger resolution. All these details will be lost. So what are other methods?

Comment: You'll have to dumb down the resolution anyways at some point, at least for collision detection. Maybe height maps are not what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that its almost impossible to load an entire 20x20 km map fully into memory. You mentioned LOD (I will talk about it later), but for now let's ignore it.

Consider a game like, let's say, Minecraft. It doesn't load all its map at once (It would be impossible, it's infinite), so it divides it in chunks (16mx16mx256m map pieces), and loads the x chunks nearest to the player. The rest of the map remains unloaded until you get closer to it.
Thats a good approximation: Split the map into pieces, and only load the pieces near the player. This, however, will have one problem: Big objects far away (For example, mountains) will be invisible until player gets unrealistically close to them, unlike in real life.

LOD is the solution to that problem. The basis of LOD is, instead only loading the parts of the map you are closest, at full resolution, load a much bigger part of the map, but reduce its resolution proportionally to the distance to the player. This makes sense: The tiny details (Grass, little holes in terrain, etc.) are only visible when you are close to them in real life, so if you load them while the player is far away, he/she is not going to be able to see them anyways, so it is a enormous waste of resources. So, for near objects, you render the world as detailed as possible and, for far objects, you reduce the detail, as the player isn't capable of noticing it anyways. Reducing the resources used this way, you will be able to load a much higher map distance than using the last approximation.

So, for your particular problem. Without LOD, it's easy. Split the "big" heightmap into smaller heightmaps, and only load the nearest heightmaps to the player. With LOD it gets more difficult, as you should, for each little heightmap, store different levels of detail (one unit per cm at first for example, one unit per 10m, or even 100m, at the end), and load one or another of them depending to the distance to the player.

Comment: but even with this i need to take care to insert vertexes at specific boundary when modeling the terrain. I will probably need to use the exported terrain mesh, but than i need LOD algorhitm not expecting heightmap

Comment: Octrees, or quadtrees if you only need to store 2D information, are good approaches to implement LOD.

Comment: Consider that there are more ways to store maps than heightmaps, but they are very handy, specially for LOD, collision detection, etc. The vertexes are easy to insert in them, as you simply have to consider every height point as a space point and draw triangles towards all collindant height points. If a height map isnt loaded yet, some height points will have some collindant height points missing, but thats no problem: You simply dont draw the corresponding triangles  until the heightmap loads and the points become available.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating a whole 20x20 km open world with enough detail for a decent-looking first-person perspective all at once is too much for even the strongest hardware.

What we usually do in this case is divide the game-world into smaller zones and only render the zones around the player in full detail. Anything further away from the player is rendered in a much lower level of detail.

When it comes to heightmaps, you could solve this by having a low-res heightmap for the whole world where each pixel represents multiple meters while also having separate high-res heightmaps for all zones where a pixel is a few centimeters. So your 0.3m crater would be represented in the high-res heightmap of the zone it's in but not in the low-res heightmap used for the whole world.